# Why does the generic type of a superclass field not get erased to the concrete bound in a subtype?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, type-erasure

```
package ir.openuniverse;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        System.out.println(A.class.getField("t").getType().getName());
    }
}

class A extends B<D> {}
class B<T extends C> {
    public T t;
}

class C {}
class D extends C {}
```

The output is `ir.openuniverse.C`. **Why? I expect `D`!**

---

<sup>EDIT:</sup>

<sup>This question wasn't about workarounds or alternative ways. So answers aren't about workarounds. For alternative ways see [myself answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236499/5318303) below.</sup>

Comment: Please edit your title to describe your actual issue.

Comment: It's more subtle than that: the type of `T` in the erasure of `B` is determined independently of the context of `A`, where `T` has a narrower bound. If you think about this, it has to be, because the compiler compiles `B` without any knowledge of `A`.

Comment: Because it was already erased to its own lower bound when it was compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of [*type erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Java compiles your generic class `B<T>` into byte code suitable for use with all classes that may reference it, including any class that may be extending `B<T>`.

Since `T` is restricted to classes extending `C`, Java knows that any value that you could assign `B.t` will extend `C`, so it compiles your class into an equivalent

```
class B {
    C t;
}
```

At this point any assignment of `t` would work; reading from `t` would yield `C`, though, so the compiler must do some "magic" to fix this. Specifically, the compiler inserts type casts in places where the subtype is known. It may also generate *bridge methods* if necessary. See the link at the top of the answer for the details.

Answer (score 1):

During compilation, Java's type erasure change

```
class B<T extends C> {
public T t;
}
```

to :

```
class B<C> {
public C t;
}
```

Since `getType()` identifies the declared type for the field, the output is `ir.openuniverse.C`

Comment: What about `class A`? That `extends B<D>`.

Comment: There is no type erasure in `class A extends B<D> {}` since it doesn't use generic types parameter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all's helps. Finally, I forced to change my `A`'s definition to:

```
class A extends B<D> {
    public D t;
}
```

It's sufficient for my purpose (although I don't like it at all!).

---

EDIT:

Above way is not a fundamental way. See *@DanielPryden*'s first two comments below.

Alternative workaround:

```
class A extends B<D> {
    @Override public D getT() { return super.getT(); }
}

class B<T extends C> {
    private T t;
    public T getT() { return t; }
}
```

And in `main()`:

```
System.out.println(A.class.getMethod("getT").getReturnType().getName());
```

Output: `ir.openuniverse.D`

---

*Another way*:

> NOTE: This is not a solution to the main problem (See *@DanielPryden*'s fourth comment below). But maybe helps you (like me).

This workaround can be used when you have at least one instance of `A`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.t.getClass().getName());
        // Or via reflection:
        // System.out.println(a.getClass().getField("t").get(a).getClass().getName());
    }
}

class A extends B<D> {
    { t = new D(); }
}

class B<T extends C> {
    public T t;
}
```

Output: `ir.openuniverse.D`

Comment: That likely won't do what you think it will, since it means that `A.t` and `B.t` will be *two different fields*, and which one you get will depend on the context of the code accessing it.

Comment: Probably what you need to do is to make `B.t` a private field, but add a public accessor method, e.g. `public final T getT() { return t; }`. With an instance of `A` this will return `D` -- the compiler will insert a bridge method that performs the cast.

Comment: @DanielPryden. Also thanks for your editing (question title).

Comment: FYI: There's no need to override `getT()` in class `A`: you'll inherit `getT()` from `B`, and because `A` inherits from `B<D>`, you'll already inherit a `getT()` method that will return `D`. (As I tried to say in my other comment, what happens underneath the hood is that the compiler will insert a bridge method that will just call `super.getT()` exactly like your hand-written one.)

Comment: In your last case, you're dealing with something completely different: the *compile-time* type of the `t` field is still `C`, but the *runtime* type is `D`. This can always happen, even if you weren't using generics: a field that is statically typed as `C` can contain a value of any subtype of `C` at runtime. Likewise, regardless of your generic bound, subtype polymorphism still applies, which is why you get these weird edge cases around covariance and contravariance. Usually you're better off using only one type of polymorphism at a time, unless you can't help it.

Comment: @DanielPryden. **1) About `getT()` overriding**: No; It's not so. I don't have your science but tested it: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/yWg. **2) About *another way***: OK. I added a note to it that says it's not a solution to the main issue.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're only looking at what Method objects you can see using reflection. If you try to actually write `A a = new A(); D d = a.getT();` then it will succeed without any warning or error, or any cast needed, whether you override `getT` in `A` or not. It's an implementation detail whether the compiler will actually generate a bridge method; I think in this case because return types are naturally covariant, there is no need (the compiler inserts a cast instead). (If `D getT()` were e.g. a method declared on an interface that `A` implements, a bridge method would be used.)